# Pass dump location to a batch file using java

Tags: java

I have a bat file to dump a database. I want to execute it with java and I want to add that dumping location using JFileChooser. Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes it is. Please show what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible. Write your batch so that it takes one argument - the dump path.

Then select the folder location using JFileChooser and execute the batch file in a Java app. The following code will create a frame with two buttons- one that selects a directory and concats the absolute path to a command string, and the other button executes your batch.

```
public class DBDumpExec {

private static final String batchCMD = "myBatch.bat";
public static String directoryChosen = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("DB Dump Executor");
    frame.setSize(450, 150);
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));

    // Display directory label
    final JLabel directoryLabel = new JLabel();
    // Button to open Dialog
    JButton openDialogButton = new JButton("Open Dialog");
    openDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setDialogTitle("Select target dump directory");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            File myFile;
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                myFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                directoryChosen = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
                directoryLabel.setText(directoryChosen + " chosen!");
                System.out.println(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    });
    // Click this button to run the batch
    JButton executorButton = new JButton("Execute DB");
    executorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // Run batch
            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        batchCMD + " " + directoryChosen);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    content.add(openDialogButton);
    content.add(directoryLabel);
    content.add(executorButton);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Read more about executing commands from [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) Javadoc.